# Change the class of a cell of a data-frame to Date

Tags: r

everyone! 
As part of my clinical study I created a xlsx spreadsheet containing a data set. Only columns 2 to 12 and lines 1 to 307 are useful to me. I now manipulate my spreadsheet under R, after importing it (read_excel, etc.).
In my columns 11 and 12 ('data' and 'raw_data'), some cells correspond to dates (for example the first 2 rows of 'data' and 'raw_data'). Indeed, this corresponds to the patient's visit dates. However, as you can see, these dates are given to me in number of days since the origin "1899-12-30". However, I would like to be able to transform them into a current date format (2019-07-05). 
My problem is that in these columns I don't only have dates, I have different numerical results (times, means, scores, etc.) .

I started by transforming the class of my columns from character to factor/numeric so that I could better manipulate the columns later. But I can't change only the format of cells corresponding to a date.

Do you know if it is possible to transform only the cells concerned and if so how? 
I attach my code and a preview of my data frame.

Part "Unsuccessful trial": I tried with this kind of thing. Of course the date changes format here but as soon as I try to make this change in the data frame it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help!

```
# Indicate the id of the patient
id = "01_AA"

# Get protocol data of patient
idlst <- dir("/data/protocolData", full.names = T, pattern = id)

# Convert the xlsx database into dataframe
idData <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(
  idlst, 
  read_excel,
  n_max = 307,
  range = cell_cols("B:M"), # just keep the table
  ), fill = TRUE)

idData <- as.tibble(idData) 

idData<- idData %>%
mutate_at(vars(1:10), as.factor)%>%
mutate_at(vars(11:length(idData)), as.numeric)

# Unsuccessful trial
as.Date.character(data[1:2,11:12], origin ='1899-12-30')
```

[image: view of the database]

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple elements of different classes in a single column. The only way I know to make it seems so is to convert all values to character format. You could probably pull the data you want appart in a new data frame then apply the modifications you want and then bind those data to the old data frame again.

Comment: You *can* have a `list`-column (to have multiple classes in a single column), but that defies a *lot* of automation in R, and many things will just not work correctly or well at all. The plague with having a "long" dataset (vice "wide") is that the values must be the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments and indeed this is one of the problems with R. 
I solved my problem with the following code where idData is my df.

```
# Change the data format of the date cells of the column Data and Raw_data:
idData$Data[grepl("date",idData$Measure)] <- as.character(as.Date(
  as.numeric(
    idData$Data[grepl("date",idData$Measure)]),
  origin = "1899-12-30"))
```